# NSIS - How can I replace the various bitmaps in the NSIS ultra-modern user interface with my own?

Tags: nsis

Good Morning,

I have a problem with the naming of the individual bitmaps. What are their names?

1. The bitmap or icon on the title bar of the windows?
2. Can I place a Bitmap in the area below the title bar too?
3. The large bitmap on the left of each page?

How can I replace the NSIS bitmaps with my own in my script?

The same goes for the Uninstall pages, and how do I show Uninstall in the start menu together with Install including the icons?

The installation and uninstallation of my Application run flawlessly, only the damned bitmaps do not work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Which defines did you try?

Answer (score 1):

All the defines are listed in the UMUI [documentation](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/SuperPat45/UltraModernUI/blob/master/Docs/UltraModernUI/Readme.html).

```
!define UMUI_HEADERBGIMAGE_BMP c:\foo.bmp
!define UMUI_LEFTIMAGE_BMP c:\bar.bmp
# UMUI_UNHEADERBGIMAGE_BMP... 
!include "UMUI.nsh"
```

Comment: If it worked then you should mark it as the answer...